# Can't login to PhpMyAdmin in a Bitnami Magento installation

Tags: phpmyadmin, magento-1.9

I installed Magento locally using the [**Bitnami Magento stack**](https://bitnami.com/stack/magento)
and during the installation I setup **user/pass**, only **once** which is good to login into the admin area. I tried to used in phpMyAdmin but it won't work.

Any workaround on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please you take a look to the Bitnami Magento Installer documentation:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/magento/#how-to-access-phpmyadmin

You should be able to access phpMyAdmin directly, by browsing to http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin.

The username is `root` for phpMyAdmin, and the password is the one specified by you during the installation process.

I hope this information is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because your login's credential related to Magento are different to your server's credential. Try using your FTP credential from your server to log into your phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm just playing around with it locally

Comment: I'm guessing you're using XAMPP, then the username is "root" and password is blank. At some point in your magento installation you had to provide this credentials

Comment: No, I'm using Bitnami. It installs Magento, the right version of PHP, Git, MySQL and Apache. Also, creates the database. As I explained before, it asked me for user and password only once which is used to login into the admin area.

Comment: Ok. I'd suggest to reinstall and read the Database section when asks for credentials. Also  look at the file database.yml in the /opt/tracks-1.7-1/apps/tracks/config directory. The password for bitnami is there.